# Displaying label text when polygon layer is rotated in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, qgis-2.8

How can i have the text labels display when the layers are rotated? I have several polygons layers rotated and i can not get the label text to display. When the rotation is removed the label texts shows but when it is rotated again it goes off.

I am running QGIS 2.8.2 Wien.

Comment: what version of QGIS are you using?

Comment: sounds like an issue that was fixed in 2.8.3 and 2.10

Comment: i am running 2.8.2 Wien.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to 2.8.3 or 2.10 or later. That issue was fixed in 2.8.3.

Comment: I have upgraded to 2.8.3 but it still persist. When i rotate the the layer the labels disappear.

Comment: @Mapperx If you are seeing this at a version later than 2.8.3 then I suggest that you update your question to say so, and to provide more precise details of your workflow so that others may be able to try and reproduce your issue.